# Rails architecture account has many accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, architecture

I need to implement following architecture for forex trading(pamm accounts)
where account(pamm account) has many accounts(other trading accounts)

I think i need to add new entity for compose accounts. am i right?

something like this?

```
class Investment < ActiveRecord 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :investments
end
```

and `AccountInvestment table` with `account_id` and `investment_id`

do i need  `has_and_belongs_to_many` association?

How i can do it properly?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but the table for a `HABTM` would be called `accounts_investments` (both plural)

Comment: @engineersmnky i just need to understand how to properly implement architecture for accounts that have many accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a tree structure, if your account is nested on many level.
Search 'rails tree model'

Simple example:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Account"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```